# DotNetOpenAuth...CreatRequest breaks on server (Works on my machine ;-)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth

I've created a site based on the ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application. I have enabled the OpenAuth login providers for Twitter, Facebook and Google by following the instructions in AuthConfig.cs.

This works fine when the site is debugged on my local machine from Visual Studio on IIS Express. However, when I copy the site over to another machine, the entire site works fince, except anything that uses open auth.

On this machine I can access twitter, facebook and google using the browser.

When I try to log on using my site I get:
for Google: "**Sequence contains no elements**" with the stacktrace pointing at

> [InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements]
>      System.Linq.Enumerable.First(IEnumerable`1 source) +514
>      DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest(Identifier userSuppliedIdentifier, Realm realm, Uri returnToUrl) +106
>
> [ProtocolException: No OpenID endpoint found.]
>      DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest(Identifier userSuppliedIdentifier, Realm realm, Uri returnToUrl) +303
>      DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.OpenIdClient.RequestAuthentication(HttpContextBase context, Uri returnUrl) +135
>      DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.OpenAuthSecurityManager.RequestAuthentication(String returnUrl) +666
>      NotesBoard.Controllers.ExternalLoginResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) in d:\dtaylor\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\NotesBoard\NotesBoard\Controllers\AccountController.cs:369
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1a.b*_17() +33
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +613
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +613
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +263
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass25.b*_22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +240
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1d.b*_18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass8.b*_3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

For Twitter I get: "**A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 199.16.156.72:443**" with the following Stack trace

> [SocketException (0x274c): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 199.16.156.72:443]
>      System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) +273
>      System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) +584
>
> [WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
>      System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +8527180
>      DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request, DirectWebRequestOptions options) +261
>
> [ProtocolException: Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response.]
>      DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request, DirectWebRequestOptions options) +1862
>      DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.RequestCore(IDirectedProtocolMessage request) +516
>      DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.Request(IDirectedProtocolMessage requestMessage) +138
>      DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.Request(IDirectedProtocolMessage requestMessage) +45
>      DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ConsumerBase.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(Uri callback, IDictionary`2 requestParameters, IDictionary`2 redirectParameters, String& requestToken) +202
>      DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.DotNetOpenAuthWebConsumer.RequestAuthentication(Uri callback) +88
>      DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.OpenAuthSecurityManager.RequestAuthentication(String returnUrl) +666
>      NotesBoard.Controllers.ExternalLoginResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) in d:\dtaylor\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\NotesBoard\NotesBoard\Controllers\AccountController.cs:369
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1a.b*_17() +33
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +613
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +613
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +263
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass25.b*_22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +240
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1d.b*_18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass8.b*_3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

Facebook on the other hand actually prompts me for a username and password but then also comes back with "**A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 173.252.100.27:443**" and the following stack trace:

> [SocketException (0x274c): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 173.252.100.27:443]
>      System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) +273
>      System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) +584
>
> [WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
>      System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request) +3624556
>      System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address) +213
>      DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.FacebookClient.QueryAccessToken(Uri returnUrl, String authorizationCode) +399
>      DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.OAuth2Client.VerifyAuthentication(HttpContextBase context, Uri returnPageUrl) +186
>      DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.OpenAuthSecurityManager.VerifyAuthentication(String returnUrl) +502
>      Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthenticationCore(HttpContextBase context, String returnUrl) +250
>      NotesBoard.Controllers.AccountController.ExternalLoginCallback(String returnUrl) in d:\dtaylor\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\NotesBoard\NotesBoard\Controllers\AccountController.cs:225
>      lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +127
>      System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +274
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass39.b*_33() +120
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4f.b*_49() +452
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4f.b*_49() +452
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass37.b*_36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass2a.b*_20() +33
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass25.b*_22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +240
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1d.b*_18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass8.b*_3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

PS. It's worth mentioning that we access the internet via a proxy, which is set up on the server in IE. I haven't found any code in the provided templates that let me specify proxy servers etc.

Help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I was able to resolve this issue. It turns out that our proxy server seems to have been the issue. I had the Application pool that was running this site in IIS configured to use NetworkServices as the Application Pool Identity. I changed the Identity to run as myself to see if the problem was resolved and it was. It's obviously not recommended to have a site run as a user account, so I will be requesting our IT team to create a domain account for this site, that also has access through our proxy servers.

I hope that helps someone else having the same problem.

Comment: Hey Gineer! even I am facing the same issue. Can you please enlighten what difference does changing the identity made. Any reason that changing the identity will make it work. Does ur identity has some additional privileges. Didn't understand how proxy change has to do anything with the identity provider.